# Measuring angle between two vectors in XNA

Tags: c#, vector, xna, rotation, trigonometry

I am creating an XNA game but am a little bit confuse working differently from the standard Cartesian coordinate when it comes to angle rotation.

Let say I have the following and I want to find the angle between those vectors

```
Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(111, 0);
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(223, 110);

float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X);
Debug.WriteLine(MathHelper.ToDegrees(angle).ToString());
```

I would imagine that angle should be close to 90 degree but it gives 44.48384.

Come to think of it, am I correct to assume that it's the angle between the horizontal line i.e Vector2(0,0) and Vector2(111, 0) and Vector2(0,0) and Vector2(223, 110)?

However if I calculate the angle using tan x = 110  / 223 the angle I get is 26.25. What am I missing?

Comment: Your calculated angle is correct.  Keep in mind that in XNA, the "up" direction is considered 0 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

The angle **is** 44.48384°, if you are measuring the angle around the origin (as you would expect, since "angle between two vectors").

Maybe you have your definition of which angle you wish to calculate envisioned incorrectly as I'm struggling to see how these two points could form the angle of 90°.

Here's a quick sketch I did on paper of these two points (please excuse the scruffiness!):

[image]

I have the Y coordinates going in the wrong direction but the problem is the same.

Comment: So for those two points,  the angle is actually measured from the x axis to the line connecting the two points? Meaning their shared origins start at (111, 0) and not (0, 0)?

Comment: Yes and no. You can measure it from the axis but it's not necessarily a correct way to look at the problem as you will again struggle when one or all of your points do not sit on an axis.

Comment: Exactly this.  If you draw a line between the two points, and if "up" is 0 degrees, you can estimate this angle to be 45 degrees.